# Getting Titanium Mobile label properties inside a function

Tags: for-loop, titanium-mobile

Problem: How to determine which of the labels is being displayed in the window.

I created labels using `Ti.UI.createLabel` and there's 6 of them in the window.  This is how I initialise them:

```
var sitCom = Ti.UI.createlabel({
    text: 'Door',
    top: 10,
    left: 5,
    visible: false
});
```

I have the same properties for other variables, the only difference is the text property.

These labels are hidden and they only get displayed on demand, when the button is pressed.  I used the `setVisible: true` to display them.  This is working fine.

I then created a function to loop through these variables to check which one is shown.  The idea is that, when the user tap a button, the script then searches for the visible ones, hide the not related ones and show the one that the button is calling for.

```
function whatIsVisible(){
   var newArr = new Array();
   var newArr[0] = 'sitCom';
   var newArr[1] = 'dutyFree';
   var newArr[2] = 'Exclusive';
   // ...

   var i = 0;
   for (i=0; i<=6; i++) {
     var v = newArr[i].getVisible();
     Ti.UI.info(newArr[i]+ ' is '+v);
   }
}
```

The function shows `undefined` in the console log.

What am I missing here?  Do I have to put an if statement inside the for loop to check the each array ?

thanks for your help

Comment: This is happening because you don't have label objects in for loop. Remove ' ' from the variables and just pass var name.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't have label objects in for loop. Remove ' ' from the variables and just pass var name.